# Play audio from specific time duration flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, just-audio

I am developing flutter application that plays audio. normally audio starts from 0 seconds but if already listened 30 seconds then by re playing it should starts from 30 second onwards. I have used ***audioPlayer.seek()*** but only slider and timer updates but audio still starts from begin.

Comment: Which audio plugin are you using?

Comment: Just_audio package

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmm. I think you're going to need to include some code before it'd be possible to tell what's going on. However, one thought is that I don't think you can seek until you've loaded the audio - if you don't load it independently and just call `play()`, I think you'd have to switch to loading before calling play.

That'd be something like this:

```dart
await player.setAudioSource(source);
await player.load();
await player.seek(Duration(seconds:30);
await player.play();
```